# Stuck on my first program/game, Hangman

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a hangman game in jQuery. This is my first time working with writing my own code/program from scratch with no references to other peoples code (GitHub).

I created a "Start Game" button that starts the Hangman game. It will then grab a random word from an array I created, 'wordBank' and store it into a variable, 'word'. I use word.length and assign it to variable, 'wordLength'. I was not sure how to convert the wordLength (ex: 6 characters in the word) to 6 blank underscores: _ _ _ _ _ _

I was not sure if that should be part of a separate function either. I'm pretty good with HTML/CSS, but now I'm trying to learn to program and have been stuck the past day on this (I started it yesterday). I appreciate anyone who gives me advice. My code is below. Thanks.

```
var wordBank = ['apple', 'orange', 'peanut'];

// grab random word from array when user clicks start

function startGame() {
    ("#start").click(function(){
        var word = wordBank[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordBank.length)];
        var wordLength = word.length;
        // convert wordLength into an underscore for each character
    });
}

startGame();
```

Comment: Without a broader view of your game logic, it's hard to say what you should do that would be relevant. For example you can simply use a for loop but that doesn't really say anything about context. How are you going to change the letters? How are you going to display them? etc. These questions should be answered first.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I wrote a bunch of steps on paper, everything I could think the game should include. I was going to make a text input for one letter at a time. I'm more of a designer so I'm trying to get into the logical thinking mindset.

Comment: anything that's used more than once *in code* should have its own `function`

Comment: Yes I'm here, sorry I had to run out for a few. Thanks everyone for your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several ways. (For each letter you get underscore and white space) 
One is to use [replace with regexp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

```
// Regex way.
var word = "abcd123456";
var userscores = word.replace(/.{1}/g, "_ ");
```

Other is to build underscores from word length:

```
// Build way.
var word = "abcd123456";
var wordLength = word.length;
var underscores = "";
for(i=0; i<wordLength; i++) {
    underscores = underscores + "_ "
}
// now variable underscores has the underscores.
```

Happy gaming :)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using your "build way" method.. I don't understand what the "/.{1}/g" part does with the regular expression. Explain if you'd like to enlighten me!

Comment: The `{1}` is actually unnecessary. `/./g` is a regular expression that means "any character", so that line replaces every character with an underscore.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Need to work on my regex knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

First: I would keep it within the same function.

Second: I would just do a for loop and print a div with a class that has a

```
.underscore{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black; 
    width:30px;
}
```

Like this:

```
var underscores ="";
for(var i=0;i<wordLength;i++){
 underscores+= "<div class='underscore'></div>";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a basic for loop, such as the following:

```
for (i=0;i<(word.length);i++) {
    document.write("_ "); //or similar function
}
```

The above will output a number of underscores equal to your word length. Adjust this if you want to store them as a variable or other such function. I would consider assigning each letter in the string to an array with the value equalling "_ " by default, then changing the value to the actual letter when they guess correctly, or some other similar means, but abstract stabs at your game logic are beyond the scope of your question as it were posed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just store an underscore for each letter inside an array? That way you could access each underscore by it's index and decide how to display them later.

```
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < wordLength; i++){
  result.push('_');
}

result.toString(); //returns _,_,_,_,_,_
result[0] //returns the first underscore
result[5] //returns the last underscore
result[2] = 'A'; // Replaces the third underscore with the letter 'A' (zero based)
result.toString(); //returns "_,_,A,_,_,_"
```

Later on, when you want to display the contents of the array you could just iterate it again. Something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) { 
  document.write(result[i] + '  ');  
}
```